# What is the difference between 'the English King' and 'the England's King'?

Tags: meaning

Is there any differece between 'the English King' and 'the England's King'? Somehow I feel they are different...

Comment: *the England's King* just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

"The England's King" is incorrect - names of countries are (with a few exceptions) not preceded by the definite article.

Assuming you mean simply "England's king", the meaning is in most cases the same as "the English king" (or indeed, "the king of England").

There may however be some differences (my historical knowledge is somewhat lacking).
For example, George III was not English by birth, so could not accurately be termed "English king."
And there may have been some British colonies that had an English king, where it would be irrelevant whether he was also the king of England (or indeed, of Great Britain or The United Kingdom, but then we're getting into another topic).

Answer (score 2):

The first might describe his ethnicity, the second (without ‘the’) his political position, but the true meaning of each would only be clear from the context.

Comment: The ony time I've encountered 'the English King' was in Jacobite documents, since George was *de facto* King in London, whereas Bonnie Prince Charlie, though he should be on the throne, was King only in Scottish hearts (or something like that).

Comment: @TimLymington: I'm sure that's right, but I was trying to answer the generic question rather than the specific one.

Comment: wouldn't "the English King" also mean he's English speaking?

Comment: @djerry: No. 'English' alone as an adjective doesn't mean English-speaking. In any case, George I came to the throne probably unable to speak English, although he could arguably be referred to as 'the English King'. And of course the Norman kings of England didn't speak English.